# How to calculate the expected number of attempts needed to succeed once when the probability increases with each failure?

Tags: math, probability

Let's say the base probability of success is .03 and each failed attempt increases the probability by .002 so that the second attempt has a probability of .032, the third .034, and so on. How can I perform a calculation or write code to solve for the expected number of attempts?

typical code for hypergeometric calculations don't seem to work for this type of problem. Obviously the answer has to be lower than 33.33 since that would be the average number of attempts when the probability remains static, and increasing probability with failure must reduce the number of average attempts to succeed. I thought perhaps we average the initial number of average attempts with the final number of expected attempts (1) when the maximum number of attempts have been made because the probability has reached 1, but it seems to me that this couldn't be the answer without further modification to this approach since it would give the same answer regardless of how much the increase in probability per failure was set to. I would guess we need to do something along these lines to calculate an average of the average number of attempts at each stage, but I'm not sure exactly how this would work or to write a calculation or code for this.

Comment: What happens when you get a success? Does the probability go straight back to .03? What do you mean by expected number of attempts? Do you mean average number of attempts to success? This is not a question about programming, so will likely be closed anyway. Try math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi. Quick word of advice: having a paragraph about the nonsense spurted by ChatGPT when you used it to give a solution to a math or computing problem tends to decrease people's desire to answer your question. If I were you I would remove that paragraph and instead focus the question on the problem and your own understanding of it, rather than on ChatGPT.

Comment: When we get a success, it ends. There are no further attempts. Or, if you like, you'd have to start again at the initial probability of .03. Yes, by expected I just meant how can I calculate the average number of attempts needed to succeed.  I know that the average number of attempts to succeed when the probability increases must be lower than 33.33 because that would be the average (1/.03) number of attempts when the probability always remains .03, but I do not understand how to calculate how much less.

Comment: Thanks Stef I replaced that bit with my own initial thoughts on how to create a calculation to solve this.

Comment: Interesting question, although it's off topic here; follow up in stats.stackexchange.com instead. The natural way to look at this is through the terminology of "survival analysis"; a web search will find some resources for that. In particular, you are describing an increasing hazard function -- i.e. the probability of failure increases over time, given that you have gotten to a given time without failure. The probability of failure at a given time can be derived from the hazard function.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation of the number of tries is equal to the sum over `k` of:

```
k * P(first k-1 tries all fail) * P(kth try succeeds)
```

There is a almost certainly a cool way to simplify this sum using mathematics, but I'm out of coffee so instead, here is a python program that will compute this sum for you:

```py
def expected_num_attempts(p0 = 0.03, inc = 0.002):
    p_success = p0
    p_allfailed = 1
    total = 0
    k = 1
    while p_allfailed > 0:
        total += k * p_allfailed * p_success
        k += 1
        p_allfailed *= 1 - p_success
        p_success = min(p_success + inc, 1)
    return total
```

Do ***not*** call this function with `inc = 0`, because the length of the loop is proportional to `1 / inc`, and it's an infinite loop with `inc = 0`.

With `inc = 0.002` the loop should have 500 iterations.

```py
print(expected_num_attempts())
# 18.000567841434215
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this in Python and really appreciate this great response. I especially appreciate the code as I come across this type of problem repeatedly.